# gradle - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not expand ZIP

Tags: gradle

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\OnerGamer>e;
'e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\OnerGamer>e:

E:>cd E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-srcE:\Project\Minecraft
\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src\decom2.bat
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

E:>cd E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src

E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src>E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\f
orge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src\decom2.bat

E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src>gradlew setupDecompWorkspa
ce eclipse

---

Powered By MCP:
 http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/
 Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
 R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn
 MCP Data version : unknown

---

:extractUserDev SKIPPED
:getAssetsIndex
:getAssets
:copyAssets
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:downloadMcpTools UP-TO-DATE
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:deobfuscateJar SKIPPED
:decompile SKIPPED
:processSources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\OnerGamer.gradle\caches\minecraft\net\minecraftf
  orge\forge\1.7.2-10.12.1.1078\unpacked\fmlpatches.zip'.

  > Invalid Timestamp -15734790866000 for 'zip entry C:\Users\OnerGamer.gradle\ca
  >   ches\minecraft\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.7.2-10.12.1.1078\unpacked\fmlpatches.z
  >   ip!net/minecraft/block/Block.java.patch'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.326 secs

E:\Project\Minecraft\mcp\forge-1.7.2-10.12.1.1078-src>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar problem with Eclipse & libGdx setup.
I did work around by ...

1. Extract the zip file manually
2. Edit the build.gradle file to skip the extract step
3. Go to Eclipse and import the project again

Hope this help.